# OpenSSL server unable to handle client disconnect with delays in between writes

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ssl, openssl

I am new to OpenSSL programming. Anyways, I have coded an openssl server and client in C (also tested in C++). When the two connect they successfully handshake and are able to read and write to each other sucessfully. I have it currently set up such that the client only reads from stream and writes to buffer, like so:

```
while((rc = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0){
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Likewise, my server is setup such that it constantly writes to stream from buffer, like so:

```
while ((rc = SSL_write(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Sent message.\n");
}
fprintf(stdout, "Done sending.\n");
```

And this works. If I were to abruptly end the client with `^C` (Ctrl C), the server would finish and print "Done Sending." However, if I were to put a delay any longer than about 10000 nanoseconds between every SSL_write (within the server's writing while loop), I get unexpected behaviour when the client disconnects abruptly (using using `^C`) or normally via counter and break.  To clarify, before abruptly disconnecting the server is able to SSL_write and the client is able to SSL_read normally between any duration of a delay (haven't tried anything past a minute).

This issue means that a client connection can effectively crash the server thread, as demonstrated by not printing "Done Sending" after the client disconnects when using delays longer than 10000 nanoseconds. I do not want the server to be able to crash because of an abrupt disconnect in a session. To be clear the server crashes on call to `SSL_write` and does not return anything.

Thing I have tried attempting to solve this issue:

- Attempting to see changes in these return values: `SSL_want(ssl)`,  `SSL_get_error(ssl,0)`, `ERR_get_error()`, and `SSL_get_shutdown(ssl)`. In some test code, I have printed all these out prior to calling `SSL_write` and none have changed their values before crashing.
- Clearing the error queue prior to every `SSL_write` using `ERR_clear_error()`
- Seeing if anything is printed with `ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr)` - nada

I have used the following delay methods:

```
// Method 1
for(long i = 0; i < (long) 99999999; i++){}

// Method 2
struct timespec tim, tim2;
tim.tv_sec = 0;
tim.tv_nsec = 10000L; // 5 milliseconds
nanosleep(&tim, &tim2);

// Method 3
sleep(1)
```

I personally think it would be ludicrous to be required to write to socket within a duration of a hundredth of a millisecond just so that the server doesn't crash on client disconnect.

Is this actually expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong or am I forgetting something? What should I do to circumvent this issue?

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @user207421 I feel dumb. Not only am I new to OpenSSL and network programming (except Java), I am new to C too, so I didn't think checking the return value (141), which you are right is indicative of SIGPIPE (128+13). I knew that you can't write to a broken socket, but I was expecting such an error to be caught by trying. That is why I tried seeing if the return values for various SSL states changed, so I might be able to figure out how to catch the issue. I used `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` (writing then returns -1). Write an answer if you want and I will select it. Thank you!

Comment: I was following various examples on the internet such as OpenSSL's own https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server But all resources I found did not handle or suggest SIGPIPE. Thanks again.